# I want to update the table column via trigger to be the same update in another table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am creating a trigger in SQL Server 2005 and I need a little help. I have a database (`ZKAccess`) in SQL Server 2005.

These databases have the different tables names.

I want table `PersonalInfo` (columns: Reg, Name, Rank, Address) user data update into table `USERINFO` (columns: Name, Lastname, Address, City) to be the same.

How can I create a trigger so that every time there is an insert / update / delete in database also gets automatically updated.

Is this possible? Could you provide some examples?

Answer (score 0):

As a simple example, this will synchronize your updates from PersonalInfo over to USERINFO (I'm not sure which way you wanted this to work, so I picked one):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TR_PersonalInfo_SyncUpdateFields]  
ON [PersonalInfo] 
FOR UPDATE 
AS
    UPDATE [USERINFO] 
    SET [Name] = inserted.[NAME], 
        [Lastname] = inserted.[Lastname], 
        [Address] = inserted.[Address], 
        [City] = inserted.[City]
    FROM 
        [USERINFO] 
    INNER JOIN 
        inserted ON [USERINFO].[KeyToPersonalInfoField] = inserted.[KeyToPersonalInfoField]
```

Inserts would be similar. For deletes, I'd recommend using foreign keys with cascading deletes, but you can certainly use triggers as well.

Comment: Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Procedure TR_PersonalInfo_SyncUpdateFields, Line 5
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Chinese_PRC_CI_AS" in the equal to operation. i have recieved this type of error

Comment: This issue has been resolve with this query COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT.

Comment: USERINFO TABLE IS ALREADY EMPTY I WANT TO MOVE THE SPECIFIC INFORMATION FROM PERSONAINFO MOVE TO USERINFO PARTICULAR FIELDS